# Error message failure and crash when using pydev embedded jython interpreter

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython

I have a strange problem when using Pydev on my work machine (others at work have the same issue).  It does not occur when I do this at home, which makes me think it's something to do with the environment at work.  We are running Windows 7.

I am using Pydev 3.9.2 but the same thing happens with earlier versions.  It occurs with all versions of Eclipse after 3.7.  The problem is this.  When I create a jython console (the one running in the Eclipse VM), the error output doesn't work.  If I type an invalid python command, there is no output on the console.  It just appears that the command worked.  If I type a command such as "print 100", the output prints as you would expect.

The second problem is that if I hit the red square which is supposed to remove the console window, Eclipse crashes.  There are no errors or any indication of what is going wrong.

I have tried different versons of eclipse, different versions of Pydev, different machines and it doesnt make any difference.

Has anyone seen this?  I've tried everything I can think of to debug this issue so any help is appreciated.

thanks,
brian

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately those quirks are expected...

The internal console in Eclipse is mostly a developers SDK for experimenting with Eclipse itself and is not meant as a general shell (you should configure an interpreter and use it for that).

I don't have plans on improving on that situation (there's already a multi-year backlog on PyDev and this isn't really critical), but if you'd be willing to spend some time and fix those issues, pull requests would be definitely welcome -- see: http://pydev.org/manual.html for details on getting the code and setting up the environment.